# How to install Qt-Jambi in Eclipse in windows 7?

Tags: windows, eclipse, installation, qt-jambi

I am new in programming and I want to install Qt-Jambi in Eclipse in windows 7.
Can you explain it to me with a step-be-step procedure?
I have searched but I didn't find a easy explaining procedure or tutorial.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4):

As a QtJambi maintainer, I provide this answer so as to help close off this issue for someone else searching.

There is no official way to install QtJambi system-wide, which might be the reason this answer has remained unanswered for so long.  Since there is no answer to the question that was put.

There is an official way to install the Java JRE or JDK that is a well trodden path using the EXE Sun/Oracle release.  But largely for Java application space and Java development space there are no official way of doing these things and the matter is largely left upto the application program and package things up and get the "ClassPath" correct for use with the application when that application is deployed.

So all I can advise to you are some ideas/tips on how you might do-it-yourself for development and application deployment.

...

Decide if you are developing for Windows 7 as 32bit or 64bit.  If you want your application to work on all windows computers (WinXP/WinVista) then 32bit maybe your choice (as there are not many desktop application that need to use more than ~1.5Gb of memory, which is about the effective usdable memory you will get, if you need this or more then use 64bit).

Once you have decide which environment you are working you need to ensure you have that Java JDK installed.  On a Windows 64bit system you can install both 32bit and 64bit JDk/JRE side-by-side.  They end up in different directories C:\Program Files\Java and C:\Program Files (x86)\Java.

If you choose to go 32bit then maybe you will also use 32bit Eclipse (and see [Trouble installing QT Jambi on a Windows 64 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545104/trouble-installing-qt-jambi-on-a-windows-64-bit-system) for help with that).  This may allow oyu to use the QtJambi GUI designer that was released (some years ago now) for Eclipse IDE.

Now you can select which QtJambi to download from sourceforge (or other download site).  This maybe just a ZIP file which you unzip where you want on your system, then setup your development enviroment to point to the JARs provided inside it.  It should not hurt to include all JARs in your classpath.

It can be useful to unzip the native JAR (that is the JAR that contains DLL/DSO inside it).  Then use the unzipped directory as a -classpath entry to java.exe.  The reason for this is that QtJambi will unpack these files since DLL/DSOs can only be loaded by the operating system when they are unpacked as regular files.  QtJambi will attempt to unpack everytime you start the EXE which will slow down development.

Other than this take a look at the source of the examples and Launcher provided in the project GIT tree on gitorious (or maybe *-src.jar in the ZIP download).

...

To deploy QtJambi as an application (to give to a 3rd party to use your application) you simply need to ensure the -classpath is setup to include the QtJambi JARs you need.

It is also recommended to deploy the Native JAR unzipped for the same reasons as above during development.  The JAR format of this data is more a convienience format to throw it around but an installed should unzip it.