# Installing QT Jambi on a Windows 64 bit

Tags: windows, qt4, 64-bit, failed-installation, qt-jambi

I'm trying to install QTJambi on my computer, win7 64 bit.

It is not duplicate to: [Trouble installing QT Jambi on a Windows 64 bit system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545104/trouble-installing-qt-jambi-on-a-windows-64-bit-system) since my problem is not loading the 64 JVM and I have setted JAVA_HOME to point to the 32 bit JDK that is in Program files (x86) folder.

When running the qtjambi.bat

I get the exception below:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambiObject.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Loading library failed, progress so far:
No 'qtjambi-deployment.xml' found in classpath, loading libraries via 'java.libr
ary.path'
Loading library: 'QtCore4.dll'...
 - using 'java.library.path'

        at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadNativeLibrary(Unkn
own Source)
        at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadQtLibrary(Unknown
Source)
        at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.trolltech.qt.Utilities.loadQtLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at com.trolltech.qt.QtJambi_LibraryInitializer.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        ... 1 more
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: C:\qtjambi-4.7.1\bin\QtCore4.dll: Can
't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
        at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary1(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Runtime.load(Unknown Source)
        at com.trolltech.qt.internal.NativeLibraryManager.loadLibrary_helper(Unk
nown Source)
        ... 6 more
```

Well, the punch line I think is:

```
 Can't load IA 32-bit .dll on a AMD 64-bit platform
```

What can I do?

Please help with detailed answer, I'm trying to follow insrtructions in teh internet for twoo days, but none is detalied enoughm and currently I cannot even start to look at the QTJambi.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3678720/how-to-install-qt-jambi-in-eclipse-in-windows-7 maybe helpful

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7545104/trouble-installing-qt-jambi-on-a-windows-64-bit-system maybe helpful (in particular my answer on setting up to use 32bit JVM on 64bit system)

Answer (score 1):

You need to use 64 bit Java with 64 bit Jambi and 32 bit Java with 32 bit Jambi. The Java binary is taken from PATH, not from JAVA_HOME, so please ensure that variable contains correct path.

Comment: or use the path to the 32bit Java EXE explicitly (assuming you have already downloaded the windows 32bit JVM and installed it on your 64bit Windows system): "C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jre6\bin\java.exe" -version